# python new character line for dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Write a function named "print_keys" that takes a key-value store as a parameter with strings as keys and integers as values. The function prints each key of the input on a separate line. That is, it prints all keys of the key-value store separated by new line characters

I've been stuck for a while on this problem and cant seem to get it. Ive tried making a for loop and concatenating with that but it isnt working how i expected it. Really need help with this, thanks.

this is what i have so far

```
def print_keys(dict):
    for key, value in sorted(dict.items()):
        print('{} - {}, {} - {}'.format(key, value[0], key, value[1]))
```

this is the error that shows
 error on input [{'spy': 9, 'stimulate': 8, 'strict': 8}]: 'int' object is not subscriptable

note the problem already has a list generated in their all i have to do is what the question is asking

Comment: Btw, each value of your dictionary is a int, not a list with multiple items.

Comment: And btw again, it's not good to name variables a builtin python keyword, that modifies the keyword to that variable's value, then the real keyword function is inaccessible. this case keyword is `dict`.

Comment: @coderfanaticbsal replace your print statement with `print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))` the examine that output. Should be able to change a bit to get your desired output. Let us know if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You code is assuming each dictionary item contains list with at-least two items - That's what the print with the `value[0]` and `value[1]` says to me.  Yet the example input there is only a single integer per dictionary item.  This is why you are receiving the "not subscriptable" error - the integer `9` is not subscriptable.  If the entry for `spy` was `[9 ,3]`, it would work fine.

Removing the index, and the next pair from the print is enough to make it work.

```
my_dict = {'spy': 9, 'stimulate': 8, 'strict': 8}

def print_keys(dict_to_print):
    for key, value in sorted(dict_to_print.items()):
        print('{} - {}'.format(key, value))

print_keys(my_dict)
```

EDIT:  Sorted by the value

```
my_dict = {'band': -1, 'yard': 16, 'universe': 8, 'dock': -3, 'missionary': 2 }

def print_keys(dict_to_print):
    for key in sorted(dict_to_print, key=dict_to_print.get):
        value = dict_to_print[key]
        print('{} - {}'.format(key, value))

print_keys(my_dict)
```

Comment: descriptor 'items' of 'dict' object needs an argument ( thats whats said when i try running it, sorry if im asking stupid questions i'm still really new to python)

Comment: @coderfanaticbsal - `dict` is a reserved word in python, although you can use it if you're careful.  I edited the code above to remove its use.  The above code worked before the change, so I assume your code does not defined the keyword `dict`, so python is going back to the reserved word.

Comment: Ah i see, so when i tried that this is the output it gave, function print_values incorrect on input [{'band': -1, 'yard': 16, 'universe': 8, 'dock': -3, 'missionary': 2}]

printed: "band - -1
dock - -3
missionary - 2
universe - 8
yard - 16"
expected: "-1
16
8
-3
2
", so i think if i take one of the brackets out it will fix this issue.

Comment: Ok, you want to sort on `values`, not `items` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value - but just using `in sorted(dict_to_print, key=dict_to_print.get)` should get you most of the way.

Comment: printed: "solid - -3
themselves - -3
cabinet - 0
hard - 3
museum - 6"
expected: "6
-3
3
0
-3
" now its asking for the values so i updated it to the one you just edited, it seems that its taking the str and the int when it only wants the int for the key value pairs. @kingsley